# Unable to merge Dex in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, google-project-tango

I'm a beginner with Android Studio.

Every time I try running my app on my Google Tango tablet, the following error emerges:

```
Execution failed for task:':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchibeMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

This is my app Module build.gradle file...

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cs15yyo.myfyp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.tango:sdk-base:1.55'
    compile 'com.google.tango:support-base:1.54'
    compile 'com.google.tango:sdk-depth-interpolation:1.55'
    compile 'com.google.tango:sdk-transform-helpers:1.55'
    compile 'org.rajawali3d:rajawali:1.1.668@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation project(':tango_support_java_lib')
    implementation project(':tango_ux_support_library')
}
```

This is my Project build.gradle file...

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my tango_support_java_lib Module build.gradle file...

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('tango_support_java_lib.aar'))
```

This is my tango_ux_support_library Module build.gradle file...

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('tango_ux_support_library.aar'))
```

### Attempted Solutions

Looking at existing solutions in StackOverFlow, I've tried the following....

- Writing `multiDexEnabled true` in the `buildConfig` block of code within the module build.gradle file
- `Build > Clean Project` and afterwards, `Build > Rebuild Project`
- Deleting the `.gradle` folder, and then running the app
- Changing each `compile` word to `compileOnly` in the dependencies of my Module build.gradle file.

All have failed me, annoyingly so.

This is for my work on my final year Computer Science project.

Comment: please add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'` I am pretty sure this will do the job.

Comment: Entered that in the dependencies of my Module build.gradle file, no success; at least, is that where I was supposed to put it?

Comment: Yes the module is the correct one. Delete both "build" dirs and rebuild project. And you'll also uncommend `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: How do I delete both "build" dirs? Would appreciate your answer to this question be in step-by-step format, thanks

Comment: 1. project/BUILD 2. project/module/BUILD (click right in your favorite file-manager "move to trash")

Comment: Ok, so I've just tried that, and now I'm getting a new error in the form of `Error converting to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/atap/tangoservice/Tango$OnTangoUpdateListener;` and then, there's a list of 15 errors

Comment: (Aside: I tend to recommend against being prescriptive about how people may answer the question. We get a lot of people asking for "need a step by step guide, plz halp", which is a sure sign that they've not done any research. That clearly doesn't apply to you, but it's worth bearing in mind when making similar requests!)

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue, as it turns out, the cause of the problem was importing JAR/AAR files as libraries AFTER writing the necessary dependencies (in the module build.gradle file) to get the same libraries; therefore, after removing the JAR/AAR files, my app was able to run